# Run jQuery animation when liquidSlider brings a particular slide into view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically what the header says. I would like to put some animations on some elements in a slide that run once the slide has loaded. Sorry not to provide any code here but I'd just like to know if this is possible. If so does anyone know the code I would have to use to trigger the effect?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#particular-slide').is(':visible')) {
 //perform animation;
}
```

Comment: Would this actually work? AFAIK liquid slider doesn't actually hide the slides it just creates a viewport and moves them in and out of view.

Comment: No it wouldn't work. You should have made a better question with code snippets and thorough explanations, rather than this minimal effort question -- which assumes knowledge of how liquidslider functions.

Comment: I'm not sure how much more specific I could have been. "Run jQuery animation when liquidSlider brings a particular slide into view".... it's quite self explanatory. When a specific slide comes into view run an animation. I suppose you could say "Run a function when liquidSlider brings a particular slide into view" but its basically the same... Thanks for the bitter down vote anyhow :). Also, you must have understood the question because you gave me incorrect code back to try and solve the problem.